# How to make jagged array to 2D array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I want to make 2D jagged array with different column lengths as 2D array with equal column lengths.
I tried converting `int[][]` to `List<List<int>>`.
For example,
How do I make

```
int[][] = 
{0,1,1},
{1,1,1,1},
{1,1,1,1},
{0,1,1}
```

**To**

```
int[][] = 
{0,1,1,0},
{1,1,1,1},
{1,1,1,1},
{0,1,1,0}  // (inserting 0 to extended space)
```

Comment: I think, you have tried something. Where did you get an error?

Comment: That's a neat requirement.  What are you having problems with?

Comment: I changed the [][] to nested List<List> and added '0' if row[column].Count is less than biggest array size. It works this way, however, my code doesn't look very clean. I was wondering if there's cleaner way to implement this.

Comment: Could you post what the code is that you've used?

Comment: Also, could you update your question to note that you changed your datatype to `List<List<int>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `int[][]` in both times, and not the alternative `int[,]` so I will ignore terminology and will assume you just want to pad 0's to make everything the same length:

```
int[][] arr = ...

int maxLength = arr.Max(x => x.Length);
var arr2 = arr.Select(x =>
                      {
                          if (x.Length == maxLength)
                              return x;
                          var y = new int[maxLength];
                          x.CopyTo(y, 0);
                          return y;
                      }).ToArray();

// now arr2 is the same as arr but with uniform lengths and padded 0's at the end
```

This approach performs many allocations. Another approach would be this:

```
List<List<int>> lists = ...

// with linq:
int maxLength = lists.Max(x => x.Count);

// without-linq:
int maxLength = 0;
foreach (var list in lists)
    if (list.Count > maxLength)
        maxLength = list.Count;
// end without-linq

foreach (List<int> list in lists)
    while (list.Count < maxLength)
        list.Add(0);
```

Choose the one you like better and better suits your situation.

You can avoid using Linq (if you want) in the first approach as well, but I didn't bother for that one.

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work for you?

```
List<List<int>> jagged = ...

var maxLen = jagged.Max(x => x.Count);
for (var i=0; i<jagged.Count; i++){
    while (jagged[i].Count < maxLen) jagged[i].Add(0);
}
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/waM72T)

Comment: you need to include System.Linq if you get an error.